# issue with NSNumber in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have converted my project to swift 3, and I have a problem with NSNumber that I cannot deal with.
Here's my number formatter declaration

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .decimal
    nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    return nf
}()
```

and here's place with error.
Value is a double, sure that other things ale fine.

```
Label.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value))
```

Message from debugger:

> Arguments labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Before conversion everything worked. Please help, I cannot find

Comment: have you tried: `Label.text = numberFormatter.string(NSNumber(value))`

Comment: @Zolnoor That's not correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
Label.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But only in this case. I have some map-stuff in my app and here: lblLocation.text = "\(numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(latestLocation.coordinate.latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude))) still error

Comment: hmm how about lblLocation.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude))

Comment: Thanks! It works! :) dont know exactly why, but works!